# Timer triggered Azure Function executes irregularly

Tags: azure, timer, triggers, azure-functions, execution

I have a timer triggered Azure Function whitch executes every morning at 04:30 AM

```
public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 30 4 * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer)
```

Now I noticed that the invocation log shows me quite different execution times:

[image: public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 30 4 * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer)]

This function worked like a charm. Since one week I notice the below issues:

How can this be that there are executions 2 minutes before the defined time? And why there are executions  up to 8 minutes (!!) after the defined time?

Another strange behaviour is that in a different environment I see that the exact same Azure Function is triggered multiple times within the same minute:

[image]

Could this be an issue with the display in the invocation log or does somebody know more about this strange effect?

Any hint is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can this be that there are executions 2 minutes before the defined time?

An error of about two minutes may be normal, which may be related to the design.

> And why there are executions up to 8 minutes (!!) after the defined time?

Processing time depends on the code you write and the size of the data processed.

> Another strange behaviour is that in a different environment I see that the exact same Azure Function is triggered multiple times within the same minute

Please check if `runOnStartup` is set to `True`. I think this is caused by multiple instances running at the same time. You can refer to this [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp#configuration).

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your inputs! Actually this behaviour has disappeared. I have no clue what happened. Maybe Microsoft was just doing some updates or similar. So I'll close this question